# Test angular form control with Playwright

Tags: angular, playwright

I'm trying to test a form control, using the Playwright framework.

The DOM is something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="usernameInput">User name</label>
<input type="text" id="usernameInput" formcontrolname="username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control text-uppercase ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-reflect-name="username" ng-reflect-ng-class="">
</div>
```

As you can see, the content of the input is not visible here, so I'm not able to access it through Playwright with this:

```
await expect(page.locator('#usernameInput').textContent()).toEqual('NAME');
```

Do you know how to access the content of a form control in a playwright test?
(the page element is correct)

Comment: Did you put a FormGroup on the form ? Did you try `formGroup.controls['username']` or `formGroup.value.[...]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the input value with `page.inputValue()`

```js
const value = await page.inputValue('#usernameInput')
expect(value).toEqual('NAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the text content, you have to assert the value. You can do this by using [toHaveValue web-first assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value).

```js
await expect(page.locator('#usernameInput')).toHaveValue('NAME')
```

Comment: I've tried this too without success